# how to forward multicast to multicast via iptables

Tags: iptables, multicast

I want to forward incoming multicast traffic to other multicast address listened on my server interface. My machine running on Ubuntu 14.04. Have a incoming traffic on 239.0.0.1 udp port 1001, want to forward to 224.0.0.1. I wrote the following rule.

 `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -d 239.0.0.1/32 -p udp --dport 1001 -j DNAT --to-destination 224.0.0.1:1001`

But there is no any traffic matching it,

`root@serv:/root# iptables -t nat -L -nv --line
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 180 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.0.0.1          PKTTYPE = multicast udp dpt:1001 to:224.0.0.1:1001`

also when I listening my p3p1 inteface with tcpdump there is show that there is incoming traffic to 239.0.0.1.

Comment: It really isn't a good idea to send anything the the All Hosts multicast group. That is reserved for network operations. If you are running software on a host which overrides the network stack to receive that group, you can mess stuff up. Without any software which listens for your traffic, the network stack will need to interrupt all your hosts needlessly, and end up dropping the traffic anyway..

Comment: OK, then how can I forward to unicast?